# Nodal analysis in simple circuit

Tags: voltage, resistors, circuit-analysis

I have a circuit to solve:
[image]

[image]

In this approach, I inferred the V1 from the parallel connection of voltage source. For the second node, I have applied the KCL.

I also tried to do it another way, by modifying the source E4 ( pushing it to the branch with G2 ) and then tried to apply nodal analysis.

Equation was like :

(G2+G1+G5)*V2=E4G2+E1G1-J

V2=(E4G2+E1G1-J)/(G2+G1+G5)

As You can see, both results differs by 'G5' in denominator. What is wrong?

Comment: Please consider cleaning up the image and moving the formula's to the text field. Check [the MathJax](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/1245/8627) while you are at it, it'll improve readability even further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If J5 is a current source, the voltage U will not depend on G5.  The correct KCL at node 2 is:

$$(U - E_4)G_2 + (U - E_1)G_1 + J_5 = 0$$

Note that there is no G5 in the above expression.  This is due to the fact that it is series with a current source.

Also, note that G3 is not in the above expression and this is because it is in parallel with a voltage source.

---

As an aside, this type of problem is easily solved by using [superposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_theorem).  Since there are three sources, there will be three terms in the superposition which are, by inspection:

$$U = E_1 \dfrac{G_1}{G_1 + G_2} +  E_4 \dfrac{G_2}{G_1 + G_2} - \dfrac{J_5}{G_1 + G_2}$$